# Open a new Gravity Form upon form validation error

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation, gravity

I am looking for the best/easiest way to open/start a new gravity form when the current form fails validation. Example: user enters a zip code that is not valid upon submission. When the form fails validation a second form opens which is used to gather user contact info so they can be notified when their zip code is available.

Does anyone have an answer already to this that I was unable to find in the search or have any ideas as to a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to tap into the action "gform_after_submission" and do a redirect to another page with that form.  http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_after_submission

Another option would be to provide a drop down list of all the available zip codes with an additional option, like "mine is not in list".  Then have some other fields that have conditional logic to only show if the "mine is not in list" value is selected. 
http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Form_Settings ( look for the conditional logic section)

Hope that helps.